# Enterprise website & webapp php framework and developement tools

Tags: web-applications, php

I'll try to be specific to make the question more answerable.
I'm a web/graphic designer and I'm basically trying to make 'the jump' towards developement (for now I know html/css well, and bits of javascript and php).
I cure an enterprise website, that I builted in Joomla, but now I feel quite limited, mainly for the rigid output layout structure. What I have to implement is:

- Robust User Management system/acl to control displayed content (the website should be used as webapp by the agents and show/hide info based on the agent and via log-in).
- Flexible layout: the website will be responsive and used in both desktop and mobile (where should be look like a native app). Plus, I'll need to associate content items to make possible to display them together (i.e.  One of the navigation paths will be: select product A > select machine for product A from a list > Land in a page with product A info   selected machine info.)
- Multilanguage
- News/events blog-like section
- Possibly some app-like features: offline navigation, auto login.
- Possibly user analytics to track user's behaviour (know if an agent downloaded a resource). [this looks  quite difficult to do]

I know there is no framework that can do something like this in a snap, especially for a novice (and that php won't be the only tool needed). What I'm looking for is a tool (or a guideline) that can implement features like that, so that I focus myself in the right way.

I've read about **Codeigniter, Zend Framework, CakePHP**, but a developer point of view would be extremely useful for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your a web /graphic designer looking to create interactive web/mobile applications I would use [Adobe CS6 Creative Suite](https://creative.adobe.com/).

You can use Dreamweaver to easily [generate a jQuery Mobile Application](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs-55-web-premium-feature-tour-/dreamweaver-cs-55-jquery-mobile/). Then just as easily connect to the built in [PhoneGap integration](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-web/updated-phonegap-support-in-dreamweaver-cs6/) and convert your application as IOS, BlackBerry, Android, and more.

Use Fireworks to [customize the jQuery Mobile](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/applications/new-in-fireworks-cs6-jquery-mobile-themes/) themes.

You can also use [Adobe Business Catalyst](http://tv.adobe.com/show/introducing-business-catalyst) to add user management, news, and e-commerce features without much coding.

Then test on multiple devices using [Adobe Shadow](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adobe-technology-sneaks-2012/adobe-shadow).

You could also use the tools mentioned and switch out Business Catlyst for another back-end system such as the ones you have mentioned Codeignite, Zend Framewor, or CakePHP.

Comment: I've never thougt of such an extensive use of adobe in web developement, but thanks, I'll dig deeper.
I'm not sure this can give enough flexibility for a quite large project as mine (with dinamic content, databases, forms etc), however can be useful tools anyway.